# Using Scroll View in Xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to use a Scroll View in my Storyboard in Xcode 6.  I want it to be 476 X 476 Pixels so it will not be scrolling down but across, left to right not up and down.  However I have not been very successful in doing this.  On the Scroll View there will be lots of buttons that can be pushed.  I have never done this before so I am not 100% sure on what I need to do.  I have put this code into the ViewController.h file and the ViewController.m file as shown bellow.

ViewController.h:

```
IBOutlet UIScrollView *Scroller;
```

ViewController.m:

```
[Scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
[Scroller setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(476, 476))];
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: Well I want to be able to scroll in my app and so I have got this grid which will be too wide for the iPhone screen, so I need to use the scroll view. I have got it placed on my storyboard and I have put the grid onto that. However it does not scroll like it is meant to. It is just normal and I only have half the grid as the other half is off the screen. So that is my issue and as you can see I have put the code in for it to work.

Comment: The scroll view needs to be completely visible. You need to set the size on its `contentView`.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: So what's your problem exactly?

Comment: How do you set the size of the Scroll View to its contentView.   I have been having a lot of trouble but all I want to do is scroll left and right.  I have put the code in as you can see above. However it is not working in the simulator when I build it.  Is there something else that I need to do to make it work?